# Is it possible to intent navigation 2 more points in google maps android?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, google-maps-urls

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=Taronga+Zoo,+Sydney+Australia");

        Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);    
        mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps"); 
        startActivity(mapIntent);
```

**It code for 2 points and what about if it will 20 points?
As I know Google Maps recommends 23 points**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8HfS.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can now use the Google Maps URLs API launched by Google in May 2017.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide

Using this API you can construct navigation URL and specify waypoints in addition to origin and destination.

So the sample code might be something like

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=Madrid,Spain&destination=Barcelona,Spain&waypoints=Zaragoza,Spain%7CHuesca,Spain&travelmode=driving&dir_action=navigate");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);    
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps"); 
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

I hope this helps!